# Do I really need Foreign key when using Pivot table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

let's say, I have a simple database with 3 tables = posts, categories and post_category (which is pivot table).

- **posts** - ID | title | body | created_at/updated_at
- **categories** - ID | name | created_at/updated_at
- **post_category** - post_id | category_id

The primary key is an ID, but I have not specified a **foreign** **key** (in posts). Should I specify the foreign key (category_id) as a column in my posts table, or is it okay to use pivot table (post_category) where I already specified the relationship between those 2 tables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pls check what a tag means before using it for a question! Only laravel refers to junction tables as pivot tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not require foreign keys to be explicitly declared, particularly with respect to querying tables.  Foreign keys enforce *relational integrity*.  That is, they ensure that tables that should refer to each other actually do refer to each other.

That said, MySQL differs from most databases by actually doing something with a foreign key declaration: MySQL builds a secondary index.  This index can be quite handy for queries by improving performance.

However, nothing is *required* about a foreign key relationship.

Comment: This is incomplete. Having category id in the posts table would imply a 1:n relationship (regardless whether fk is used), whereas the current structure means an n:m relationship.

Comment: @Shadow Having a column tells you nothing. There is only a 1:n relationship if a FK could be declared; the column could be there without a 1:n relationship. It all depends on what the tables mean, ie what rows are to go into them given a situation. You do not need to know any constraints to query. They follow from the table meanings & what situations can arise.

Comment: @philipxy having the primary key of a table as a field in another table does tell you something - that the two tables are related in a 1:n manner. Otherwise it is pointless to have the pk of the other table as a field. The presence of an FK - as Gordon has pointed out in his answer - just enforces relational integrity.

Comment: @Shadow Since that contradicts my last comment, we'll have to disagree.

Comment: @philipxy provide just 1 rational example where you place the pk of a table as a field in another table and that does not imply a 1:n relationship. If you cannot provide such a credible example, then you are simply wrong.

Comment: @Shadow mycats(animalid), mydogs(animalid), favouritepets(animalid). Now I'll stop chatting under a third party's post.

Comment: @philipxyph which will all point to a common animal table indicating the 1:n relationship...